# Multi-signature Account with Wait Time

Tags: permissions, multisig, deferred-transactions

I want to create a shared hierarchical account using time delays and multi-sigs. 
My intention is to use a "wait" time delay in conjunction with a mutli-sig proposal.  I want to require a multi-sig permission between 2 accounts and a wait time like:

```
myaccount
permissions:
    owner 4:    3 myaccount@active, 1 bobsaccount@active, 1 aliceaccount@active, 3 wait time of three days, 1 wait time of 1 hour
        active 1:    1 ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

here bob and alice could use the @owner permission with a 3 day wait time, and myaccount@active could supersede their actions with a 1 hour wait time.

However, to perform a multi-sig action you must propose an action and the authorities needed to approve it.  I am stuck because I would need to propose a multi-sig action with a delayed time, and I do not know how to do this.

I was able to figure out how to use the "wait" time delay in a simpler use case.

For example, if I had an account like

```
myaccount
permissions:
    owner 2:    2 myaccount@active, 1 bobsaccount@active, 1 wait time of 3 days
        active 1:    1 ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

bobsaccount can use myaccount@owner with a wait time of 3 days (3 days = 259200 seconds)

```
cleos wallet import BOBS_PRIVATE_ACTIVE_KEY
cleos push action eosio.token transfer '["myaccount", "anotheraccount", "5.0000 EOS", "memo"]' -p myaccount@owner --delay-sec=259200
```

and this will work

Answer (score 0):

You would add the specified delay in the `delay_sec` option for the multi signature.

You can see this in the Transaction Settings here: https://www.bloks.io/wallet/msig.

Not that the delay does not begin until the minimum threshold is met with the delay.